# Skip a partical node while showing connection in graph view

Tags: neo4j, microservices, devops

In a graph DB (Neo4j), I need to maintain inventory of all the existing resources in a microservices-based architecture. For this I have to create 2 views, a top level view and a detailed view.

Consider this is my relationship:

```
Node(lambdaXYZ) -[r:API_CALL]- Node(NatGatewayABC) -[r:API_CALL]- Node(ec2ABC)
```

but I want 2 different types of views:

1. the first is the above view type
   `lambdaXYZ -> NatGatewayABC -> ec2ABC`
2. second is a summary view which is something like this
   `lambdaXYZ -> ec2ABC`

Basically I want to skip some nodes and show only a preview.
This is because I need to have NatGateway in the database to store the IP address from etc.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I don't see the difference between these two views

Comment: sorry i updated the question .. the summary view skips the NatGatewayABC

Comment: I'm not familiar with a way to present in the UI a relationship which does not exist on the graph. You can create such a relationship...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a [virtual relationship](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/virtual/virtual-nodes-rels/) to represent a "summary" path (going from from the first `Node` to the last `Node` in some actual path).

For example, here is how you can create a `SUMMARY-CALL` virtual relationship between the `lambdaXYZ` Node and the last Node in any chain of outgoing `API_CALL` relationships (up to length 7):

```
MATCH (n1:Node)-[:API_CALL*..7]->(n2:Node)
WHERE n1.id = 'lambdaXYZ' AND NOT EXISTS((n2)-[:API_CALL]->())
RETURN n1, n2, apoc.create.vRelationship(n1,'SUMMARY_CALL',{}, n2)
```